# Swift window hierarcy warning solution?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have question about window hierarchy. When I try to login app and go to home controller first time, I can't go any page which from home controller and console gave this warning:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

I tried to make viewdidappear code but its not working.. 
I didn't use storyboard. I make present home controller in this code:

```
   func logUserIn(withEmail email: String, password: String) {
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print("Failed to sign user in with error: ", error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }


        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let homeController = HomeController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeController)
        self.present(navController, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: I presume you try to present a VC from a presented view controller and is not working. Check in what VC this function is and how is displayed.

Comment: @Andreas777 Actually home controller presented correctly but from home controller I can't go other page and console gave this warning. When I re open app everything working correctly.

Comment: You can't present a VC over another VC. You have to dismiss previous one to present a new one

Comment: @Andreas777 I understand but why its working when user open app again? Its only make this error first time.

Comment: you should also make sure you do your presenting and stuff in the main thread